# Error while creating subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am trying to create sub site using CSOM. The parent site is having webtemplate as "GROUP". But I am receiving following error message.

> Value does not fall within the expected range.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
>   sb)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Here is my code for creating subsite

```
      ClientContext _context = null;
   SPWeb f_Web = null;


  _context = new ClientContext("https://Mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/office365");
  _context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(m_Userid,
                                      m_SecurePassword);
  f_Web = _context.Web;

  _context.Load(f_Web, website => website.Webs);
  _context.ExecuteQuery();

  WebCreationInformation wcf= new WebCreationInformation();
  wcf.Description   = "This is subsite";
  wcf.Language      = 1033;
  wcf.Title         = "MySubSite";  
  wcf.Url           = "newsubsite";
  wcf.WebTemplate   = "STS#0";
  wcf.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = true;
   f_Web.Webs.Add(wcf);
   f_Web.Update();
  _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please suggest the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try GROUP#0 in  wcf.WebTemplate   = "GROUP#0";

Comment: @NadeemYousuf   still same error

Comment: how about `wcf.WebTemplate  = "STS#0";` ?  you can't create a group subsite

Comment: @GautamSheth : Its giving error as "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.". But I am able to create subsite manually

Comment: ok, can you share the full code that you are using to create subsite ? Looks like the account you are using to create subsite programatically doesnt have adequate permission or you are not passing the credentials correctly

Comment: @GautamSheth; I just browse the subsites in browser and I can see newly crearted subsites using wcf.WebTemplate = "STS#0. But at same time its throwing above exception. Updated  my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is combination of CSOM and Powershell.

The First section is used to connect to the SharePoint Online Site that you wish to create the Subsite within, simply update the highlighted $Site variable with the relevant URL.

The second section creates a SubSite within the Site Collection. Update the highlighted variables to match your requirements, I've used the Team Site template (STS#0) in this example.

```
#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your username"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$Site = "https://site.sharepoint.com"
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Create SubSite
$WCI = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebCreationInformation
$WCI.WebTemplate = "STS#0"
$WCI.Description = "SubSite"
$WCI.Title = "SubSite"
$WCI.Url = "SubSite"
$WCI.Language = "1033"
$SubWeb = $Context.Web.Webs.Add($WCI)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```